# UWP - Change Tooltip height/width

Tags: c#, uwp, tooltip

I'm leveraging a tooltip to show more details for every row in a grid. 
Details are shown as grid columns inside the tooltip, but I'm not able to change the tooltip width to show them all.

I tried changing the tooltip Width, MinWidth, MaxWidth properties, and even the internal grid width; but the tooltip always remains the same size.

**.CS**

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Opacity = 0.3;
rect.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
rect.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 7);
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure);
rect.Margin = new Thickness(2);

MyTooltip mt = new MyTooltip(par);
mt.Style = Application.Current.Resources["LargeToolTipStyle"] as Style;

rect.SetValue(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, mt);
```

**STYLES.XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="LargeToolTipStyle" TargetType="local:MyTooltip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <ContentPresenter
                                 x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                                 MaxWidth="800"
                                 Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                 Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                 ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MYTOOLTIP.XAML**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Client.MyTooltip"
    ...
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Name="TooltipGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="TooltipHeaderTBL" Text="LEFT HEADER" 
               Grid.Column="0">
        </TextBlock>
         <TextBlock Name="TooltipHeaderTBR" Text="RIGHT HEADER" 
               Grid.Column="1">
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="TooltipContentTBL" Text="Content sample (L)" 
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="TooltipContentTBR" Text="Content sample (R)"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Please provide your XAML to understand better how you tried to do this. please read how to ask questions with [mcve].

Comment: Could you please explain why this post has been downvoted AFTER adding new details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was right there: **the style must be applied to a Tooltip object**.

I was directly assigning the User Control as ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, and then tried to edit the User Control style.

Defining a ToolTip object with the desired style, and assigning my User Control as its Content, did the trick.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Opacity = 0.3;
rect.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
rect.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 7);
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure);
rect.Margin = new Thickness(2);

MyTooltip mt = new MyTooltip(par);

ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
t.Content = mt;
t.Style = Application.Current.Resources["LargeToolTipStyle"] as Style;

rect.SetValue(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, t);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `MaxWidth` of `ToolTip` is 320 at default according to the [ToolTip styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299160.aspx). Since the `ToolTip` style doesn't open the `MaxWidth` property for setting that it may take no effects if you directly set `MaxWidth` property for `ToolTip`, only properties such as `Foreground`, `Background`, `Padding` and so on can directly setting. So you may need to update the `MaxWidth` for the `ContentPresenter` by changing the default style for the `ToolTip` as follows:

```
 <Rectangle
     Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
     Fill="Azure"
     Opacity="0.3">
     <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip>
             <ToolTip.Style>
                 <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                     <Setter Property="Template">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                                 <ContentPresenter
                                     x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                                     MaxWidth="2000"
                                     Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                     Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                     ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                     TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                                             <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                                 <Storyboard>
                                                     <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                                 </Storyboard>
                                             </VisualState>
                                             <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                                 <Storyboard>
                                                     <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                                 </Storyboard>
                                             </VisualState>
                                         </VisualStateGroup>
                                     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                 </ContentPresenter>
                             </ControlTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Style>
             </ToolTip.Style>
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   ...
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   ...
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <TextBlock
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Text="testtriptext on column 0testtriptext on column 0testtriptext on column 0testtriptext on column 0" />
                 <TextBlock
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="testtriptext on column 1" />
                 <TextBlock
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     Text="testtriptext on column 2" />
             </Grid>
         </ToolTip>
     </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
 </Rectangle>
```

Comment: Edited above: I am trying to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: This is the right hint, thanks @Sunteen Wu! Just had to get the same results programmatically.